# Can i validate filter params using django-filters with some exeption if params or filter-params are wrong?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter, django-filters

I incapsulate some logic for inheritance to for drf views.
If i am using wrong field-param or wrong fild-filter (for example param with filter is:        ?title__contains=title, and on frontend we made some mistake), i just get Model.objects.all() query from self.filter_queryset without any exception, but i gues that django-filter validate params inside filter_queryset method. I will be very grateful for the hints in which direction I need to look.

Hear i'm using django-filters:

```
class SomeView(GenericAPIView):
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    some = SomeDTO()
    
    def some_get(self, request: Request, serializer: serializers):
        model = serializer.Meta.model
        params = request.query_params
        if params:
            query = self.filter_queryset(model.objects.all()) # problem is hear!
        else:
            query = model.objects.all()
        self.some.collect(serializer(query, many=True).data, status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return self.uni
```

Drf-views looks like:

```
class CurrentView(SomeView):
    filterset_class = CustomerFilter

    def get(self, request: Request):
        some: SomeDTO = self.some_get(request, CurrentSerializerDepth)
        return Response(some.data, some.status)

    def post(self, request: Request):
        some: SomeDTO = self.some_create_or_update(request, CurrentSerializerFlat)
        return Response(some.data, some.status)
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a custom `FilterSet` class that throws an error when an invalid query-parameter is given:

```py
from django_filters.rest_framework import FilterSet
from rest_framework.exceptions import ParseError


class AcceptOnlyDeclaredParametersFilterSet(FilterSet):
    """FilterSet that throws an error when an invalid parameter (filter-field) is given."""

    def check_allowed_parameters(self):
        """Check if the given parameters are allowed. Raises a ParseError if they are not."""
        non_allowed = [param for param in self.data.keys() if param not in self.declared_filters.keys()]
        if non_allowed:
            raise ParseError(f"Unknown filter parameters: {non_allowed}")

    def is_valid(self):
        """Check if the filter contains valid parameters."""
        self.check_allowed_parameters()
        return super().is_valid()
```